# If target withing the body is not a label tag, do hide something

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

How can I say that when I click anywhere within the body if the clicked html element is not a label do something?

I currently have this code:

```
$('html body').click(function(event){

        if($(event.target) != $('label')){
          //do something
          alert('not label');
        }
}
```

This is not working and the alert is displayed no matter what I click.

Comment: `$('label')` is selecting none or multiple `label` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `tagName` property of the element:

```
$('html body').click(function(event){
    if (event.target.tagName != 'LABEL'){
        alert('not label');
    }
}
```

Or you could use jQuery's `is()`:

```
$('html body').click(function(event){
    if (!$(event.target).is('label')) {
        alert('not label');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this help me out. Found out what the problem was. Apparently the input checkbox below the label is also activated when i click on the label.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you jQuery's diversity, here's another option:

```
$(document.body).on('click', ':not(label)', function () {
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aum93auz/

```
$("html body").on("touchstart click", function( event ) {
if ( $( event.target ).is( "label" ) ) {
          alert('label');
    } else {
        alert('not label');
    }
});
```